# Default-network and default-gateway

Tags: cisco, routing

When would you choose to use the `ip default-network` command instead of the `ip default-gateway` command?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ip default-gateway` is to be used in L2 devices.

`ip default-network` would be used in L3 devices, but works slightly different from the usual static default route configured with `ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 <next_hop>`. Let's say you configure `ip default-network 172.31.0.0`. Then, if the device already knows a route for 172.31.0.0, this route will be flagged as a default route candidate.

You need to take into account that `ip default-network` command is classful.

Further details and clarifications are available [here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk365/technologies_tech_note09186a0080094374.shtml#ipnetwork)

Answer (score 2):

See [here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk365/technologies_tech_note09186a0080094374.shtml)

Basically `ip default-gateway` is for layer-2 devices and `ip default-network` is for layer-3 devices.

`ip default-network` is basically a default route

Answer (score 1):

When IP routing is enabled, the commands ip default-network and "ip route 0.0.0.0" etc. work the same. These commands would be used on a router or Layer 3 switch.

"ip default-gateway" would be used when ip routing is not enabled - for instance, on a Layer 2 switch that has an SVI for management but cannot route on that SVI.